# How to transfer ownership out of an @autoreleasepool with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I have the following code

```
- (NSString *)stringByEscapingXMLEntities;
{   
    NSString *result;
    @autoreleasepool {
        result = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
        result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"];
        // ... lot of -stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: calls
        result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"&nbsp;"];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I ask myself now how would I transfer ownership `result` out of the method. Before ARC I would have retained `result` before exiting the autorelease block and returned it autoreleased at the end of the method.

Thanks!

Comment: here's what I tried so far: returning within the autorelease pool; defining result as __strong and having the method return a retained object;

Comment: Do you still have autorelease pools under arc?

Comment: Does what you have there not work?  I would have thought that the compiler, knowing `result` was declared outside the scope of the pool, would add the necessary retain.

Comment: Above example does not work. Have a test on Mac OS that crashes. Also let's assume the autoreleasepool is necessary. It's basically just something I want to fully understand why it's not working.

Comment: That code works for me. Could we see the code that's crashing? There may be a better fix for the real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

- Rename the method to something like `copyStringByEscapingXMLEntities` -- the `copy` indicates the transfer of ownership and ARC creates the code accordingly.
- Append, in the header, `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` to the method definition like this: `- (NSString *)stringByEscapingXMLEntities NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`.

---

**EDIT:** As 'iljawascoding' mentioned, the `@autoreleasepool` has no real need to be kept around -- except for optimization.

---

**EDIT 2:** And remember: *ARC always does the right thing*. All the things you tried (your comment) result in the very same correct program -- albeit with the lack of some optimization if result was defined as `__strong`.

Comment: but is there a way to do this without changing the method signature?

Comment: The second method, append `NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED` to the header. The method name and signature stays the same -- it's just an attribute. Problem is that the compiler needs to know the behavior in the class and for every call -- and the only way for that is the public interface. No other way round.

Comment: Sorry, just saw I meant `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` instead of `NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED`. ;)

Comment: This answer is nonsense. Making the method return a retained value does not affect how ARC (correctly) handles the transfer out of the autorelease pool scope.

Comment: @Ahruman: The question clearly states: "I ask myself now how would I transfer ownership result out of the method". And hence the answer.

Comment: If you then read the next sentence, it then clarifies that the OP wants the semantics ARC gives with the unmodified code.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the autorelease altogether. According to Apple, ARC will automatically insert the necessary release after your code is done with the temporary instances stored in 'result'. There's nothing to gain by rolling your own autorelease pool here.

Comment: The autorelease pool *could* make sense if the method is called very often and one wanted to make sure the interim objects were drained.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted is correct. Any crash has a different cause.

Because `result` is a strong reference outside the autorelease scope, ARC is responsible for keeping it alive when exiting the pool, and it does. You don’t need to do anything special.

More specifically, ARC generates code equivalent to this:

```
void *_arp = objc_autoreleasePoolPush();
temp1 = objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue([self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"]);
temp2 = objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue([temp1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"]);
objc_release(temp1);
result = objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue([temp2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"&nbsp;"]);
objc_release(temp2);
// result is not released here
objc_autoreleasePoolPop(_arp);
return objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(result); // Result is returned autoreleased, or handed off to a  matching objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue() in the caller.
```

Note that the temporary variables are handled with `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`/`objc_release` pairs. Because of the runtime optimization implemented by `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` and `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`, this means that the temporary values will actually be released immediately without ever being put in an autorelease pool *if* `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` is built with ARC. My guess would be that most of the system frameworks aren’t yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:result]` before the `@autoreleasepool` scope closes? But why the ARP in the first place?